# Xcode - How come sometimes definitions are in white and sometimes colored?

Tags: ios, xcode

When I want to view a definition on Xcode, I would use Control + Command + Click to jump to a definition. However, sometimes the syntax will be colored, sometimes it'll be all in white. Does anyone know why that happens sometimes and how to fix it?

Here's an image of how it's supposed to look. I'm trying to recreate it where it'll show all white, but I have no clue how that happens or how to fix it when it happens other than waiting.

[image: Colored Definition]

Why this happens or is this just a bug with Xcode?

Comment: If you're considering the possibility that it's a bug, then you should specify the exact version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

It happens sometimes when Xcode is running the App, or indexing, or doing something else.

Just wait a little while it finish processing its current task.

By the way, you can change some Navigation options in this tab :

[image]